# Store data in array as an input file in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have an excel or text file that have some digits as a data. I want to load it to python and store them in a matrix. what can I do? (my excel file has 3 rows and 20 columns).

Comment: What problems did you meet after reading one of the many tutorials a simple google search yields?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file should be in some format. Excel files can be exported to `csv` format, than you can use Python's `pandas` module, the typical workflow is simple

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("mycsv.csv")
```

now `data` object is pandas.DataFrame object. *Basically* a 2D array.

Comment: pandas can easily read Excel files directly - `pd.read_excel()`